# WARNING The requested profile "preprod" could not be activated because it does not exist

Tags: maven, jenkins

I created profile for respective preprod but in jenkins build facing the issue like:

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "preprod" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1.jbossorg-3:exec (default-cli) on project mbddx-calc-engine-services: Misconfigured argument, value is null. Set the argument to an empty value if this is the required behaviour. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your project `pom.xml` with the following profile:

```xml
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>preprod</id>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

or exclude that goal from mvn command you run by adding  `-P!preprod`. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Deactivating_a_profile)